# How does session work in express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, cookies

I come from php background, so without any framework I simply do session_start() and after user login I'll do session['username'] = 'sam' and in every route I check whether session['username'] exist or not, else redirect them to login page.

But in express I'm seeing lots of option like in the express-session npm

```
var session = require("express-session");
var sessionMiddleware = session({
    secret: "secret",
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    maxAge:365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
});
```

This npm also generate cookie, why cookie come into the picture here? if you use session why do u need to use cookie? I'm confused.

Comment: So how do you think php sessions work? How does php distinguish between 2 different clients?

Comment: @zerkms 2 different cilents means? no idea. teach me mastar.

Answer (score 2):

HTTP is a stateless protocol. It can not identify the users or sessions by itself. So how do most languages platform do this? They generate an unique ID for that user and store that in a cookie. And they store all the session data on the server side, using that unique ID to differentiate between user sessions.

So in PHP, when you do `session_start()`, it generates a cookie named `PHPSESSID` or something similar. Then PHP stores all the session data in a file or in a database on the server, against that key. Every time the user visits the different pages, PHP reads the value of that cookie and gets the ID. Based on that ID, PHP retrieves the session data and makes them available as `$_SESSION`.

The same thing is true for almost all web frameworks, including express.

Comment: Good explanation, but when u mention session, it's actually have to do with cookie? I've seen people storing session cookie in file server or db, why? isn't it enough to be in the memory of the server-side?

Comment: Yes, it can be stored in memory but memory can be volatile and less persistent.

Comment: @masnum so it is advisable to store session cookie in db? that makes every request required call from the db.

Comment: Yes and still many people do that. For persistence and reliability.

Comment: really? I don't see that been implemented or practice in new framework like angularjs

Comment: no. I mean angularjs simply consume the api, and the server side is java. And I did not see their store session in db.